# How to add load from and save to file support for binary/depth=1/bilevel image in FileIO of julia?

Tags: file-io, imagemagick, julia, binary-image

Objective:

To save a bi-level image to file as Array{Gray{Bool},2}, but not of type Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2}.

It is understood from https://github.com/JuliaIO/FileIO.jl, that new formats for loading from and saving to file can be defined.  I am new to image processing.

Please guide me in adding binary image format to FileIO to load from and save to file.

Comment: Hello again! So you're new to image processing, and want to define your own file format straight away? I'm impressed by your ambition! :) I don't know how to create binary image formats, so ... good luck!

Comment: First thing to do would be to open an issue requesting that functionality at the github repo of FileIO.jl Someone might already find that interesting and add it, or you may get guidance on how to prepare a pull request yourself.